# How to Limit the amount of logs sent by fluentd to elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, fluentd, rancher

I would like to be able to limit the amount of logs sent by a fluentd daemonset to elasticsearch per day (index), so fluentd stops sending when fluentd has sent more, than, let's say, 10GB for a given day.

I know that it is possible to control the buffer, but for me, this is not enough. I want to ensure a maximum of GB logged by each project, in order to be sure that the elasticsearch cluster will cope with all of them with the assigned resources.

Any hint of how to do this? Another possiblity for me would be to limit the size of the elasticsearch index, but this (if possible) would result in errors in fluentd and buffer overflow.

Thanks!